# How to run a specific project when you have multiple projects in xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa

If you have a xcode project like restkit that has the core code for restkit + examples that have their own project, how do you run a specific project?

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/

If you look at the /Example's folder, you will see they have a few of them and each have their own project file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple targate in xcode.

> A target specifies a product to build and contains the instructions
>   for building the product from a set of files in a project or
>   workspace. A target defines a single product; it organizes the inputs
>   into the build system—the source files and instructions for processing
>   those source files—required to build that product. Projects can
>   contain one or more targets, each of which produces one product.